# iOS Web App Display

Tags: ios, safari, iphone-standalone-web-app

I have created a web app that, for the last step of user interface, leads a person to a web site which generally displays a pdf file, but which sometimes can be a normal web page. Everything works perfect when I launch the app from mobile Safari. However, when I save the app to the iPhone desktop, and run the app there, when the user gets to the web page, they have no way of going back to the app to make another selection, and thus another web page. When using Safari, there is always the back button.

I have tried setting the following to NO :

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
```

That did not change the behavior. I'm not sure how to further characterize this problem, but in essence, when launching the app from the iPhone "desktop," when the user loads an external web page, I cannot get back to the main app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd remove that line completely from the web page, delete the bookmark from the home screen, and try again.

Comment: I ended up putting the line in there, with content="NO," deleting the bookmark from the homepage, and trying again. It worked this time! So, I'm good to go. Thanks!